# what is new in Ubuntu 13.10 & migration criteria

Tags: 13.10

Since the emergence of Ubuntu 12.04, the experts recommended it. Even after 2 versions(12.10;13.04), this recommendation remains valid.My questions are: how can you compare the two versions(12.04 & 13.10 ) to know if it is right to migrate to 13.10.
 If we find that the latest version is stable,this criterion may be sufficient for Ubuntu 13.10 migration. What are the new features of Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the main reason would be to have a newer version of software without the hassle with ppa's. there are some small changes in the launcher but for me that would not be enough to update. also keep in mind that 14.04 again is a long therm support version, this is half a year away and LTS versions in general are more stable, if you can do without the newer versions of software I would wait with upgrading till 14.04.